# Why the contents of welcome page in jsp isn't loading?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jakarta-ee, eclipse-jee

i have made one project on E-Commerce using JSP technology of JEE, in that i have assigned a page named as home.jsp as a welcome page of my project. The page is located in the home_page folder of the Web Contents folder of my project. But when i run the project the contents of home.jsp don't get loaded in the browser page. I am attaching the code of the welcome page and the screenshot of the default welcome page in the browser apart from that i am also attaching the screenshot of the welcome page which is expected to come when the project executes.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/home_page/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

[image: default welcome page]

[image: Actual desired welcome page]

Comment: you are giving `absolute path` try with `relative path`

Comment: What is the URL you're using?

Comment: @Prashant What is the difference between absolute path and relative path? Please clear it up using some kind of example. Thank you.

Comment: @AtulMittal : suppose you are giving `home.jsp` with respect to `C or D drive` in windows  or `/home/` in unix  then it will be `absolute path` but if you are passing something like `../home.jsp` or `home.jsp` then it will be `relative path` to your current directory.

Comment: First off - trailing or leading `/` are not allowed in the `<welcome-file-list>`. What exactly is the URL you're requesting @AtulMittal ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "/" at the end of the URL you're trying to access. It should fix it if you have servlets mapped in your web.xml.